# Updating r plot_ly chart by drop down menu

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly

I have simple example of plotly chart and found very interesting drop down menu functionality within of plotly charts ([link](http://moderndata.plot.ly/new-feature-dropdown-menus-in-plotly-and-r/)).

When I tried that on very simple mtcars example, it seems to be not updating during switching items in drop down menu.

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars$disp, mode = "markers", name = "A", visible = T) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.8,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("x", mtcars$mpg),
               label = "mpg"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("x", mtcars$disp),
               label = "disp"))),
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("y", mtcars$hp),
               label = "hp"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("y", mtcars$wt),
               label = "wt")))
))

p
```

What I'm doing wrong. Please, could you help me on that. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of plotly you use?

Comment: I'm using plotly_4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some syntax errors, change it to something like this should work appropiate:

```
p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x= ~mpg, y= ~hp, type="scatter", mode = "markers")
p %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(title = "y"),
  xaxis = list(title = "x"),
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      y = 0.8,
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "animate",
             args = list("x", list(~mpg)),
             label = "mpg"),
        list(method = "animate",
             args = list("x", list(~disp)),
             label = "disp"))),
    list(
      y = 0.7,
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "animate",
             args = list("y", list(~hp)),
             label = "hp"),
        list(method = "animate",
             args = list("y", list(~wt)),
             label = "wt")))
))
```

Version: `plotly_4.5.2`

Comment: Thanks a lot, great solution!!! Is there any way how to get xlab and ylab based on drop down selection (yaxis = list(title = "y"))?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have no solution for this. [Here is](http://community.plot.ly/t/dropdown-with-multiple-attribute-changes/2005) a discussion about multiple  values in the `args`, but I can't tranfer it to `R` and found no solution to update the titles, because they are set within the layout. For upadting they should be specified in the plot function I guess.